# In memory and custom providers all together

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm setting up my Spring Security (v4.0.1) web application. I want to have two authentication providers, an "in-memory" one to manage the administrator account and a custom one which refers to my own implementation. The system should attempt the authentication against the "in-memory" provider first of all and against the custom one in second place. My code looks like this:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, 
    AuthenticationProvider provider) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("s3cr3t")
            .authorities("ADMIN");
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}
```

However, this code leads the framework to try my custom implementation first. It makes a bit of sense, since the [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder#authenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) method adds a Provider to the internal List while the [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder#inMemoryAuthentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) one configures it internally. How could I manage to get it work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create your `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` manually and tell it to configure itself on the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` when you have finished configuring it so it installs it's `AuthenticationProvider` before your custom one:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
        AuthenticationProvider provider) throws Exception {

    inMemoryConfigurer()
        .withUser("admin")
            .password("s3cr3t")
            .authorities("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .configure(auth);
    auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
}

private InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder>
        inMemoryConfigurer() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<>();
}
```

Normally what happens is that the `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` is created and added to the list of configurers that should be applied when the `AuthenticationManager` is built - which is after you've installed your custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

Answer (score 3):

More or less from [spring.io Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/reference/core-services.html)

If you are using XML configuration (e.g. spring-security.xml):

```xml
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="FirstProvider" />
    <security:authentication-provider ref="SecondProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

(I am using that setup for one of Spring's built-in authentication provider next to a custom one, works fine)

If you are using Java Config, I can only reference some other person's post [maclema on Java config for multiple authentication provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799080/2039709), since I have never (successfully) tried code config

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not using the XML configuration. What I want to achieve is something similar to your linked answer, but instead of having two custom authentication providers, I've got a custom one and other in-memory one, which is provided by Spring. As the in-memory one is defined over the AuthenticationManagerBuilder, I don't know how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Today we tend to configure Spring Security via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you register filters that extract credentials from a request and register providers that use tokens built by filters by populating `Authentication` object with other details like authorities:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter tokenPreAuthProcessingFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    http.addFilterAfter(tokenPreAuthProcessingFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // First.
    auth.authenticationProvider(new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider());

    // Second.
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .withUser(...);
}
```