# spring boot perform ldap and database authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, ldap

My application has 2 types of users, first would never have a LDAP id and their authentication is going to be via DB and second would have a LDAP id and their authentication would be via LDAP.
My DB has a flag on the authentication type (LDAP or DB) and roles. Even after LDAP authentication, I need to access my DB to get the roles(Hope this can be retrieved using UserDetailsService)
I did go through few links showing how multiple authentication provider can be used or a custom authentication can be used. But I am unable to make a concrete decision on how to go about this. I have not put any code because I am still finding how to go about this. Please suggest the best approach for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794680/multiple-authentication-mechanisms-in-a-single-app-using-java-config

Comment: Thanks for the link, Its useful